# How do I export a simple Blender 3D model, without armature, to Three js?

Tags: scripting, export, three.js

I have googled it and have found a little or close to no info.The existing info is for old versions of blender and three js.
I have tried this method https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender, but I am not seeing "Import-Export: Three.js Format" in the Addons in blender.
I have Blender 2.72, and three.js (r70).
UPDATE:
I have been able to export my simple cube model into .JSON file type.
Now how should I upload and use it in three.js?

Comment: According to the docs you should do this. `File` -> `Export` -> `Three.js` the rest is self explanatory.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Blender 2.73 and three.js (r70)

The io_three folder has to be copied to blender's scripts/addon folder for the "Import-Export: Three.js Format" to appear. But this has probably been figured out by you.

During the export to three.js (.json) format you may want to include a few essential and additional attributes like vertices,faces,colors and materials for your model. By default, the following will be checked.

[image]

Depending on the complexity of the image, you may get texture files in addition to the .json files. Use them.

Now you have to basically re-create the model using a scene, camera, renderer and animation loop.

A tutorial with three.js basics --> http://www.kadrmasconcepts.com/blog/2011/06/08/three-js-blender-part-2/